# header menu is not fixed in Agency - Start Bootstrap Theme

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i am using Agency - Start Bootstrap simple one pager html theme . theme is working fine. but i went to make changes that i added one new division with big image.

here is my code .

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">
```

```
<div class="navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img style="height:55px;width:150px;" src="http://unicca.in/images/logo.png"></img></a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>



    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right  "  >
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#page-top"> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Corporate</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#tools">Buyer Tools</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#investor">Investor</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
        </div>
```

please check how this website looks like

[mysite](http://www.neurotrauma2015.org/templates/unicca/)

problem:
 i want that header menus after my big image . but its coming over that image. how to do that . i have tried lot in changing a css but its giving some other problem . how to fix it .

my css file is [css link](http://www.neurotrauma2015.org/templates/unicca/css/bootstrap.css)

imp: if used navbar-staic-top rather than navbar-fixed-top then its coming down but it will not worked as fixed menu.

Answer (score 0):

Then you change your html div structure like this add position fixed on scroll with jQuery

```
<div class="my-class">
<!--add banner div-->
<div class="banner">
  <img alt="myhome" style="width:100%;height:700px;"     src="http://cdn.freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/selling-your-home-exterior-home-color.jpg">
</div> 

<!--add nv div-->
<div class="navbar-default navbar-shrink"><!--remove nav-topbar-fixed div-->
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img style="height:55px;width:150px;" src="http://unicca.in/images/logo.png"></a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right  ">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#page-top"> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Corporate</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Career</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#tools">Buyer Tools</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#investor">Investor</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

CSS : remove position fixed

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse{
  position: fixed; /**remove**/
}
```

Comment: where ? in css file ?

Comment: in your agency.css line no 189

Comment: no. its not working . its coming over that image only

Answer (score 0):

Nayana, You Mean that menu will always showing on the bottom of the browser, right? if then, try this , edit `agency.css` and change `.navbar-fixed-top{top:0px}` to `.navbar-fixed-top{bottom:0px}`